# jquery accordion - close sections only on second click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I use accordion (jquery UI) and I don't want to close sections when click on the other, only when click on the already opened section. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: @Edward No, I normally use accordion $("#accordion").accordion(); Nothing special.

Comment: sounds like you simply need to find the .on('click') handler for your accordion sections and tweak the bits where it allocates the active classes. I am not really familiar the jQuery-ui accordion, but that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui accordion avoid closing item wnen clicking on another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119503/jquery-ui-accordion-avoid-closing-item-wnen-clicking-on-another-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An accordion doesnot allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time.Read [JQuery UI documentation for Accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/).Usually what you want to achieve can be written with few line of jquery code itself as below

```
$('#accordion h3').click(function() {
      $(this).next().toggle('slow');
  })
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yqTkN/)