# Open all Sections of Jquery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using this 
[Jquery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

It allow only one section to open at a time but i want to open the zone as much as i want.For example if I have 3 sections and if I click on 2 of them both of them should remained open. How to do this?
Any Help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui accordion avoid closing item wnen clicking on another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119503/jquery-ui-accordion-avoid-closing-item-wnen-clicking-on-another-one)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I wrote **[a little plugin](https://github.com/TouPye/multiaccordion.jquery)** for that, feel free to use and modify it

It is based on jQuery UI's Accordion, using the same classes.

It is pretty simple to use :

---

**JS** :

```
$(".accordion").multiaccordion();
```

---

**HTML**

```
<script src="multiaccordion.jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <h3>Simple Accordion 1</h3>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce in facilisis orci. Vivamus dapibus feugiat.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h3>Simple Accordion 2</h3>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="accordion">
      <h3>Nested Accordion 2.1</h3>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce in facilisis orci. Vivamus dapibus feugiat.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <h3>Nested Accordion 2.2</h3>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce in facilisis orci. Vivamus dapibus feugiat.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

*NB : CSS provided is a personnal thing*

Answer (score -1):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: This will not allow 2 of them to stay open. It will allow only that they all can be closed :)